# Как можно переделать код с itertools на обычный код без import и сделать функцию через yield(Питон)

Tags: python, функции, list, генераторы, yield

Есть код

```
from itertools import chain, cycle, compress


def generate_step(a, *steps):
    selections = chain.from_iterable(
        [0] * (step - 1) + [1] for step in cycle(steps)
    )
    return compress(a, selections)


a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
b = generate_step(a, 1, 2)
print(next(b))
print(next(b))
print(next(b))
print(next(b))
print(next(b))
```

Вывод:

```
1
3
4
6
7
```

Он работает, но мне нужно, чтобы он работал без использования `import`.
В моём коде это не генератор, потому что нет `yield`, мне также нужно, чтобы в переработанном коде был `yield` вместо `return`. И соответственно в конце нельзя выходить за границу списка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
def generate_step(a, *steps):
    i = 0                                      # начинаем с первого элемента
    step_index = 1                             # начинаем с шага2, не очень логично,
                                               # но так указано в примере 
    while i < len(a):                          # пока не закончатся элементы во входном списке
        yield a[i]                                  # генерируем текущий элемент
        i += steps[step_index]                      # переходим к следующему элементу
        step_index = (step_index + 1) % len(steps)  # переходим к следующему шагу
```

Comment: Вы написали, что не очень логично начинать с шага2 и я с Вами согласен. А как начать с шага 1 тогда? что нужно заменить?

Comment: а я понял, нужно просто ```step_index = 0``` сделать, я правильно понял?

Comment: да, правильно поняли